# SPARQL MAX using AJAX call returning a forbidden error 403

Tags: ajax, sparql, jena, fuseki

I have an ajax call to get the max id bigger than 200. Up to a few months ago, this worked fine but now I am getting a 403 forbidden error. The ajax call is sending the query to an Apache Jena Fuseki server and this is the code I have:

```
  function getNextId(){
     myQuery= ["PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>",
     "PREFIX locah: <http://data.archiveshub.ac.uk/def/>",
     "prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>",
     "SELECT (max(?id) as ?maxId)",
     "WHERE{",
     "?item dcterms:identifier ?id.",
     "?item locah:item ?i.  ",
     "FILTER(xsd:integer(?id)>200)}"].join(" ");
     
     $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: 'jsonp',
       cors: 'true',
 
      url: myEndPoint,
     data: {"query": myQuery,
     "output": "json"},
     success: successId,
     error: myError
     });
     console.log('After .ajax');
 
 }
```

The funny thing is that when I use the same query directly on the fuseki server this works just fine. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: obvious questions: 1) which Fuseki version? 2) does any other query work, e.g. `select * {?s ?p ?o} limit 10` 3) have you tried to restart Fuseki or is it already a fresh running one? 4) what did you change in the "few month"?

Comment: 1) Fuseki Version 3.12.0 2)  Yes it does 3) Yes I restarted it 4) Nothing!

Comment: I am noticing that even with other queries I am getting an error 403 but a simple select like the one mentioned works just fine

Comment: did you try to encode the query via using `encodeURIComponent(myQuery)` instead of just `myQuery` in the data param part?

Comment: 403 is a permissions error. The query did not get to the query engine. Maybe the `myEndPoint` is wrong or the `cors`.

Comment: That is my suspision that the cors is incorrect. Any idea how I can fix that?